# MIME Date Header Time Zone

Tags: email, time, timezone, mime, email-headers

In some MIME emails I see the header "Date: Fri, 24 Aug 2012 08:36:35 UT". The time zone at the end "UT", seems to be inconsistent. Sometimes it's UT, sometimes it's GMT, sometimes it's +0100.

I have two questions:

1. Is the 24 Aug 2012 08:36:35 already standardized to GMT/UTC or some other time?
2. If not, what exactly are the possible values of the time zone at the end? The 'UT' seems to be an atypical abbreviation (I only see 'UTC'), and '+0100' is definitely is different from 'GMT' and 'UT'.

Comment: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2822#section-3.3

Comment: Thanks. I couldn't find the documentation. That helped alot.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is no difference between UTC(Coordinated Universal Time) and GMT(Greenwich Mean Time) and both are common standard format of defining time unit. In MIME, always(mostly) date is mentioned in this standard format only to avoid confusion among timezones if date header is available.
+0100 is defining that time is in GMT and means GMT time + 1 hour
and refers Italian timezone.

Italy - GMT +100
India - GMT +530

Hope this clarifies your questions.